# Estimation fiber length of overlapping fibers from image using python code

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I need a help in estimating the accurate fiber length from image. I have developed code in `python` through which estimation of length is possible up to some extent.
I have used `Skan` opensource library to get the diameter & length of fiber segments from `skeletonized` image of fiber. I am facing challenge in tracing the fiber at overlapping point or at Junctions for length estimation. Currently the estimated length is much small than actual image as it estimates only length of segments till the junction point from end point of fiber.  It would helpful if anyone can help in estimating all overlapping fibers length. Sharing the `code` and original image for reference.

[image: Original image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage import morphology

img00 = cv2.imread(r'original_img.jpg')
img_01 = cv2.cvtColor(img00, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img0 = cv2.cvtColor(img00, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

i_size = min(np.size(img_01,1),600) # image size for imshow
# Creating kernel
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
  
# Using cv2.dialate() method 
img01 = cv2.dilate(img0, kernel, iterations=2)
cv2.imwrite('Img1_Filtered.jpg',img01)

ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img01,245,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresh = (thresh1/255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('Img2_Binary.jpg',thresh1)

# skeleton based on Lee's method
skeleton1 = (skeletonize(thresh, method='lee')/255).astype(bool)
skeleton1 = morphology.remove_small_objects(skeleton1, 100, connectivity=2)

# fiber Detection through skeletonization and its characterization
from skan import draw, Skeleton, summarize
spacing_nm = 1   # pixel

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
draw.overlay_skeleton_2d(img_01, skeleton1, dilate=1, axes=ax);

from skan.csr import skeleton_to_csgraph
pixel_graph, coordinates0 = skeleton_to_csgraph(skeleton1, spacing=spacing_nm)

skel_analysis = Skeleton(skeleton1, spacing=spacing_nm,source_image=img00)
branch_data = summarize(skel_analysis)
branch_data.hist(column='branch-distance', bins=100);
draw.overlay_euclidean_skeleton_2d(img_01, branch_data,skeleton_color_source='branch-type');

from scipy import ndimage
dd = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(thresh)
radii = np.multiply(dd, skeleton1);
Fiber_D_mean = np.mean(2*radii[radii>0]);
criteria = 2 * Fiber_D_mean; # Remove branches smaller than this length for characterization

aa = branch_data[(branch_data['branch-distance']>criteria)];
CNT_L_count, CNT_L_mean, CNT_L_stdev = aa['branch-distance'].describe().loc[['count','mean','std']]
print("Fiber Length (px[enter image description here][1])  : Count, Average, Stdev:",int(CNT_L_count),round(CNT_L_mean,2),round(CNT_L_stdev,2))
```

Comment: Are you able to detect the junction points? You could try to compute the entering/leaving line directions at those junctions and compute the likeliness of each pair to couple. Maybe you can also find a graph algorithm for that, like bipartite matching.

Comment: @Micka: a graph does not have a geometry, it is not sufficient to correctly match the pieces.

Comment: @YvesDaoust the graph would need weights of direction similarity at a junction point in the original skeleton. So for each junction you need a bipartite matching between 4 points.

Comment: @Sushil: Have added a code example to my answer. Please check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the skeleton I would proceed as follows:

- convert the skeleton to a path graph
- for each pair of paths identify valid junctions
- calculate the angle between each adjacent path
- merge paths that go nearly straight through the junction

Here is a sketch that can find overlapping fibers in the skeleton. I leave it to you to optimize it, make it robust against real life images and how to derive statistics from the results.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology, graph
from skan import Skeleton

MAX_JUNCTION = 4    # maximal size of junctions
MAX_ANGLE = 80      # maximal angle in junction
DELTA = 3           # distance from endpoint to inner point to estimate direction at endpoint


def angle(v1, v2):
    rad = np.arctan2(v2[0], v2[1]) - np.arctan2(v1[0], v1[1])
    return np.abs((np.rad2deg(rad) % 360) - 180)


img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# dilate and threshold
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
dilated = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilated, 245, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# skeletonize
skeleton = morphology.skeletonize(thresh, method='lee')
skeleton = morphology.remove_small_objects(skeleton.astype(bool), 100, connectivity=2)

# split skeleton into paths, for each path longer than MAX_JUNCTION get list of point coordinates
g = Skeleton(skeleton)
lengths = np.array(g.path_lengths())
paths = [list(np.array(g.path_coordinates(i)).astype(int)) for i in range(g.n_paths) if lengths[i] > MAX_JUNCTION]

# get endpoints of path and vector to inner point to estimate direction at endpoint
endpoints = [[p[0], np.subtract(p[0], p[DELTA]), i] for i, p in enumerate(paths)] +\
            [[p[-1], np.subtract(p[-1], p[-1 - DELTA]), i] for i, p in enumerate(paths)]

# get each pair of distinct endpoints with the same junction and calculate deviation of angle
angles = []
costs = np.where(skeleton, 1, 255)  # cost array for route_through_array

for i1 in range(len(endpoints)):
    for i2 in range(i1 + 1, len(endpoints)):
        e1, d1, p1 = endpoints[i1]
        e2, d2, p2 = endpoints[i2]
        if p1 != p2:
            p, c = graph.route_through_array(costs, e1, e2)       # check connectivity of endpoints at junction
            if c <= MAX_JUNCTION:
                deg = angle(d1, d2)                               # get deviation of directions at junction
                if deg <= MAX_ANGLE:
                    angles.append((deg, i1, i2, p))

# merge paths, with least deviation of angle first
angles.sort(key=lambda a: a[0])

for deg, i1, i2, p in angles:
    e1, e2 = endpoints[i1], endpoints[i2]
    if e1 and e2:
        p1, p2 = e1[2], e2[2]
        paths[p1] = paths[p1] + paths[p2] + p   # merge path 2 into path 1, add junction from route_through_array
        for i, e in enumerate(endpoints):       # switch path 2 at other endpoint to new merged path 1
            if e and e[2] == p2:
                endpoints[i][2] = p1
        paths[p2], endpoints[i1], endpoints[i2] = [], [], []    # disable merged path and endpoints

# display results
for p in paths:
    if p:
        img1 = img.copy()
        for v in p:
            img1[v[0], v[1]] = [0, 0, 255]
        cv2.imshow(f'fiber', img1)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: out0.png] [image: out1.png]

[image: out2.png] [image: out3.png]

Comment: Markus: Thanks... Actually I am quite new to python and image analysis part as well. It would be great if you help me to write code with the above steps....