# How can I find the angle of the curves marked in the picture below?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform, corner-detection

[image: Processed Image]

Is there any way that we can compute the angle of each corner identified in the picture?
Is Hough Transform applicable here? or is there any other way?

I've identified the corners using OpenCV and need help in computing the angle of each corner identified.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: dot product maybe?

Comment: This answer starts with a simple function to calculate angles. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72196895/18667225