# I need to measure these plasma filaments, looking for length and maximum thickness

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I have multiple photos of plasma filaments like these:

[image: 1m] [image: 2m] [image: 3m] [image: 4m]

... where the filament is interrupted on top of the image by shielding. I would need to do some image analysis that includes the length of the filaments and, if possible, their maximum width. For the images, where the filament is interrupted I would need to connect white spots and interpolate it like it wouldn't be interrupted.

I tried to use [a code I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167844/estimation-fiber-length-of-overlapping-fibers-from-image-using-python-code) but it only accepts black and white images.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Mar 16 20:44:05 2024

@author: janko
"""

import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology, graph
from skan import Skeleton

MAX_JUNCTION = 4    # maximal size of junctions
MAX_ANGLE = 80      # maximal angle in junction
DELTA = 3           # distance from endpoint to inner point to estimate direction at endpoint


def angle(v1, v2):
    rad = np.arctan2(v2[0], v2[1]) - np.arctan2(v1[0], v1[1])
    return np.abs((np.rad2deg(rad) % 360) - 180)


img = cv2.imread('M2ohX.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# dilate and threshold
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
dilated = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilated, 245, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# skeletonize
skeleton = morphology.skeletonize(thresh, method='lee')
skeleton = morphology.remove_small_objects(skeleton.astype(bool), 100, connectivity=2)

# split skeleton into paths, for each path longer than MAX_JUNCTION get list of point coordinates
g = Skeleton(skeleton)
lengths = np.array(g.path_lengths())
paths = [list(np.array(g.path_coordinates(i)).astype(int)) for i in range(g.n_paths) if lengths[i] > MAX_JUNCTION]

# get endpoints of path and vector to inner point to estimate direction at endpoint
endpoints = [[p[0], np.subtract(p[0], p[DELTA]), i] for i, p in enumerate(paths)] +\
            [[p[-1], np.subtract(p[-1], p[-1 - DELTA]), i] for i, p in enumerate(paths)]

# get each pair of distinct endpoints with the same junction and calculate deviation of angle
angles = []
costs = np.where(skeleton, 1, 255)  # cost array for route_through_array

for i1 in range(len(endpoints)):
    for i2 in range(i1 + 1, len(endpoints)):
        e1, d1, p1 = endpoints[i1]
        e2, d2, p2 = endpoints[i2]
        if p1 != p2:
            p, c = graph.route_through_array(costs, e1, e2)       # check connectivity of endpoints at junction
            if c <= MAX_JUNCTION:
                deg = angle(d1, d2)                               # get deviation of directions at junction
                if deg <= MAX_ANGLE:
                    angles.append((deg, i1, i2, p))

# merge paths, with least deviation of angle first
angles.sort(key=lambda a: a[0])

for deg, i1, i2, p in angles:
    e1, e2 = endpoints[i1], endpoints[i2]
    if e1 and e2:
        p1, p2 = e1[2], e2[2]
        paths[p1] = paths[p1] + paths[p2] + p   # merge path 2 into path 1, add junction from route_through_array
        for i, e in enumerate(endpoints):       # switch path 2 at other endpoint to new merged path 1
            if e and e[2] == p2:
                endpoints[i][2] = p1
        paths[p2], endpoints[i1], endpoints[i2] = [], [], []    # disable merged path and endpoints

# display results
for p in paths:
    if p:
        img1 = img.copy()
        for v in p:
            img1[v[0], v[1]] = [0, 0, 255]
        cv2.imshow(f'fiber', img1)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So I edited a code to this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology, graph
from skan import Skeleton

MAX_JUNCTION = 4    # maximal size of junctions
MAX_ANGLE = 80      # maximal angle in junction
DELTA = 3           # distance from endpoint to inner point to estimate direction at endpoint


def angle(v1, v2):
    rad = np.arctan2(v2[0], v2[1]) - np.arctan2(v1[0], v1[1])
    return np.abs((np.rad2deg(rad) % 360) - 180)

img = cv2.imread('DSC_7987.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)


# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# skeletonize
skeleton = morphology.skeletonize(thresh, method='lee')
skeleton = morphology.remove_small_objects(skeleton.astype(bool), 100, connectivity=2)

# split skeleton into paths, for each path longer than MAX_JUNCTION get list of point coordinates
g = Skeleton(skeleton)
lengths = np.array(g.path_lengths())
paths = [list(np.array(g.path_coordinates(i)).astype(int)) for i in range(g.n_paths) if lengths[i] > MAX_JUNCTION]

# get endpoints of path and vector to inner point to estimate direction at endpoint
endpoints = [[p[0], np.subtract(p[0], p[DELTA]), i] for i, p in enumerate(paths)] +\
        [[p[-1], np.subtract(p[-1], p[-1 - DELTA]), i] for i, p in enumerate(paths)]

# get each pair of distinct endpoints with the same junction and calculate deviation of angle
angles = []
costs = np.where(skeleton, 1, 255)  # cost array for route_through_array

for i1 in range(len(endpoints)):
    for i2 in range(i1 + 1, len(endpoints)):
        e1, d1, p1 = endpoints[i1]
        e2, d2, p2 = endpoints[i2]
        if p1 != p2:
            p, c = graph.route_through_array(costs, e1, e2)       # check connectivity of endpoints at junction
            if c <= MAX_JUNCTION:
                deg = angle(d1, d2)                               # get deviation of directions at junction
                if deg <= MAX_ANGLE:
                    angles.append((deg, i1, i2, p))

# merge paths, with least deviation of angle first
angles.sort(key=lambda a: a[0])

for deg, i1, i2, p in angles:
    e1, e2 = endpoints[i1], endpoints[i2]
    if e1 and e2:
        p1, p2 = e1[2], e2[2]
        paths[p1] = paths[p1] + paths[p2] + p   # merge path 2 into path 1, add junction from route_through_array
        for i, e in enumerate(endpoints):       # switch path 2 at other endpoint to new merged path 1
            if e and e[2] == p2:
                endpoints[i][2] = p1
        paths[p2], endpoints[i1], endpoints[i2] = [], [], []    # disable merged path and endpoints

# display results
for p in paths:
    if p:
        img1 = img.copy()
        for v in p:
            img1[v[0], v[1]] = [0, 0, 255]
        cv2.imshow(f'fiber', img1)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but I get this error:

```
C:\Users\janko\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py:219: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\janko\onedrive\muni\bakalářka\fotky_k_analyze\analyza_fotek.py:84
    img1[v[0], v[1]] = [0, 0, 255]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: maybe you could ask on [forum OpenCV](https://forum.opencv.org/)

Comment: for the filament interruption: you could try some techniques of image _inpainting_. Here you have an [example](https://learnopencv.com/image-inpainting-with-opencv-c-python/) using an algorithm based on fluidodynamic techniques (Navier-Stokes). It's purpose is to fill a "small" region so for bigger one one should iterate the method.

Comment: suggestion: it's all guesswork anyway, so just find the best "height" those filaments reach. if you don't care about the number of filaments, just take a slice through the image and calculate sum "thickness". -- yes, all of this may require some thresholding. -- if you need fancier analysis, you would have to explain what the analysis is *for*. you know, convey understanding of how these filaments form, why they appear as they do, what affects their appearance, and who needs what parameters of these things for what purpose, and with what quality.

Comment: don't even consider inpainting. that's not leading anywhere. the inpainting itself adds no information AND it requires you to know those gaps already you are looking to do measurement here, not photographic manipulation. I would have stronger words for that but not here.

Comment: I want length, not height, but maybe the height must be sufficient. I need the length filament to analyse the plasma jet and its behaviour. If I change the power output to the plasma jet, the length of the filament(s) changes and I'm trying to figure out how.

Comment: do you expect these things to become very curvy?

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/i-want-to-determine-length-of-filaments-from-image/16856

Comment: concerning that code you found, which you say "only accepts black and white images", assuming you want to stick to that code, what have you tried to make it fit your purpose?

Comment: I asked on the Opencv forum because I tried another approach. Here is how it can be curvy: https://ctrlv.link/1QmU

I tried to get the image in the code by Otsu's thresholding with Gaussian filtering but I'm still getting some errors. Now it's an error in the display results block:  int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[199], line 5
    img1[v[0], v[1]] = [0, 0, 255]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: in that last picture you linked to, what are the fluffy spots beyond the tip of the right filament? -- those are mere programming errors. unless you present the exact code that caused the error, there's no way any of us could help you. -- your problem shouldn't be the programming though, but the theory, which is image processing, computer vision/machine vision/measurement.

Comment: The fluffy spots beyond the tip of the right filament are the filament covered by shielding and they should be involved in length of the filament

Comment: I mean the latest one you linked in the comments, the third that is now in the post. https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4hVk.jpg

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to edit my question to include the new code I used. Still, I get an error: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut." even when I didn't change anything. I tried what the error message says but it didn't help. So I don't know what to do now.

Comment: put your code between \`\`\` at the beginning and end of the code. no need to indent. your question already uses this style.

Comment: I triedthat and it didn't work. I got error even when I changed nothing in the post

Comment: sometimes this site can be frustrating. throw it up on some random pastebin. I'll try copying it into the post then. maybe more rep will let me do it.

Comment: here it is: https://pastebin.com/jq2fus5D

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first and last row containing a non-zero element.

```
raw = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(raw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = cv2.normalize(image, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)
_, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

You can adjust the thresholding arguments, or use another method, such as adaptive tresholding. Here you can find more: [OpenCV tresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

```
non_zero_pixels = cv2.findNonZero(binary_image)
y_coordinates, x_coordinates = non_zero_pixels[:, 0, 1], non_zero_pixels[:, 0, 0]
y1, y2 = min(y_coordinates), max(y_coordinates)
x1, x2 = min(x_coordinates), max(x_coordinates)

height, width = y2 - y1, x2 - x1
print("Height: ", height, "px.   Width: ", width, "px.")

cv2.rectangle(raw, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Image", raw)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It is not clear whether, when a flame splits into several flames, you need the width of the outer contour of these flames or rather the widths of the individual sub-flames.

In the latter case, you can simply write a function that iterates over the lines between y2 and y1, and when the first non-zero pixel is encountered, counts the subsequent pixels until the first zero is encountered, and so on. Then, the accuracy will depend on the precision of the thresholding.

Comment: the filament splits in two when reaching a certain power output on the plasma jet. It's a little bit unknown what the precise conditions for splitting are. I would need a width of individual sub-flames.